# Distinguish a file and a folder in linux

Tags: linux, file, directory

in linux command I want to move all files with 's' to a folder 'test1' with the following command

```
mv *s* test1/
```

It worked but at the end, an error was shown 'it is not possible to move the folder to itself'.

I'm curious, how can I specify, only move file with 's', not folder.

Answer (score 0):

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*s*" | xargs mv -t ./test1` this command will only copy files that start with the letter `s` and ignore folders.